# Latest Parity Guide

Tags: parity

There is no one place to get the **Latest** guide on parity software usage and Ethereum plateform. All guides—which are scattered on various places—are beyond understanding for a new being. Please provide authentic and comprehensive information links or resources.

Answer (score 0):

[Their Wiki](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki) contains a good source for all of this information.
Go down through the index and you should find what you need.